# How do I write a script that runs "du -sh" for every file in a directory?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

My organization has a network share dedicated to user files. Each user has their own directory. I am trying to figure out who is using the most space on the share. My current code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

#Author= x
#Date= 04/28/23
#Desc= x

# Defining the directory
directory="/path/to/directory"

# Creating array to hold the file names
files=()

# Loop through each file in the directory
for file in "$directory"/*; do
  # Add the file name to the array
  files+=("$file")
done

# Use du to get the size of each file and sort the results by size
du -sh "${files[@]}" | sort -h > output.txt
```

When running the script I receive "du: cannot access '$file': No such file or directory." I am fairly new to scripting, and realize this problem is with how I am defining my variables, but not sure what to change.

Comment: Why not just: `du -h * | sort -h`  ???

Comment: the script you posted looks right to me (apart from being overcomplicated as they said). On the other hand, the error message looks like you're doing `files+=('$file')` there instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating it. As Gilles pointed out in a comment, just:

```
du -sh /path/to/directory/* | sort -h
```